# ScaleDrawable does not work?

Tags: android

.

I need to set an image from assets of my application to an imageview. My condition is that, the image which i going to set should be of same width and height as of Image previously set from drawable.
  For that i have created a small code as follows:

```
  {
        ImageView myImgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
        int height=myImgView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
        int width= myImgView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        Drawable draw=Drawable.createFromStream(assetManager.open(drawableFolder+"/"+tmpArr[0]), null);
        ScaleDrawable scd=new ScaleDrawable(draw,0, width, height);
        view.setImageDrawable(scd);
}
```

But ImageView shows nothing, Image gets disappeared. So please can anyone tell me where i am going wrong , or any other solution.

Thankx in advance . .